# How could we use hashmap as a variable in where block

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spock

I want to put a SET here, how?
I googled this `spock where block new HashSet` did get any result.

```
    @Unroll
    def "Sample"() {
        expect:
            .....
        where:
        base | exponent || result1 | result2
        1    | 2        || 1 | {{I want to put a SET<ID> here, how?}}

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not just a Spock newbie (I noticed in your previous question) but also a Groovy newbie. No problem. :-) You should rather google for `groovy set literal` and find something like [this page](http://grails.asia/groovy-set-examples).

In Spock you can either define the variables in the `where:` block as method parameters for your feature method (test method) including giving them types like this:

```groovy
@Unroll
def "sample"(int base, int exponent, int result1, Set<Integer> result2) {
  expect:
  result2 instanceof Set

  where:
  base | exponent || result1 | result2
  1    | 2        || 1       | [1, 2, 3]
}
```

This would cast or coerce the list literal into a set. Or you can save a lot of typing and just use the Groovy `as` operator as shown on the page I linked to:

```groovy
@Unroll
def "sample"() {
  expect:
  result2 instanceof Set

  where:
  base | exponent || result1 | result2
  1    | 2        || 1       | [1, 2, 3] as Set<Integer>
}
```

Instead of `Set<Integer>` you would use `Set<Id>` whatever your `Id` class might be.

Comment: u got me. I'm a newbie to both! Thanks a ton!!